# Using sed in AWS Lambda to Delete Rows

Tags: python, csv, aws-lambda, sed

I have a Python AWS Lambda which is bulk inserting some csv data into a `Postgres` database using the `copy` command. One line uses `sed` to remove the headers from the csv:

```
subprocess.run(f"sed -i '' {local_path}", shell=True)
```

This is fine on my Mac, but isn't working in the Lambda environment. What should I be using instead?

Alternatively, is there a way to do this in Python? I haven't found a way to directly edit the file to remove the headers without copying every line minus headers to a new file, which seems like overkill.

Comment: You can't use `sed` as it's not available within Lambdas - I know COPY in Postgres can work based on streams but I've only used the copy streams in Java. Can you not read the file as a stream (pipes in Python *I think*), discard the first 'line' or `x` amount of bytes until the new line character (just as an example) and then provide the rest of the stream (i.e. file without the header) to the copy command? Depending on how big the file is and how long it takes to read it, you could read, pop first row and then write it back to the same file as a last resort.

Comment: ok, I went with your last option for ease. Just copied to a new file without the headers. Sometimes simplest is best!

Comment: No worries - feel free to self-answer your question or I'm happy to write up an answer.